# How to reset password of AWS Cognito user?

Tags: javascript, amazon-cognito

If I click the "reset password" button for a user in the AWS Cognito, all it does is re-send the verification email, containing the account registration email code.

However, if the user takes that code and enters it on the verification page, AWS returns the error:

```
NotAuthorizedException: User cannot be confirmed. Current status is RESET_REQUIRED
```

First, how do I get Cognito to send a real "password reset" email instead of the "confirm your registration" email?

I assume it's giving me this error because the verification JS is calling:

```
createCognitoUser(email).confirmRegistration(code, true, function confirmCallback(err, result)
```

and not some undocumented password reset function. What function should I be calling?

Answer (score 1):

You should be calling forgotPassword.  From the AWS Documentation at [Using Amazon Cognito User Identity Pools Javascript Examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-javascript-examples.html):

```
cognitoUser.forgotPassword({
    onSuccess: function (result) {
        console.log('call result: ' + result);
    },
    onFailure: function(err) {
        alert(err);
    },
    inputVerificationCode() {
        var verificationCode = prompt('Please input verification code ' ,'');
        var newPassword = prompt('Enter new password ' ,'');
        cognitoUser.confirmPassword(verificationCode, newPassword, this);
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem is that Cognito only allows you to include one link in your email, and that email is used for both new user registrations, and apparently password resets. How do you tell whether to call `confirmRegistration` or `forgotPassword`?

Comment: I changed jobs, so I don't have access to the code base.  If I recall correctly, that's all driven by the state of the client application.  Login page has a username and password, a register link and a forgot password link.  If you click register, it takes you through a confirmation workflow.  If you click forgot password, it takes you through a forgot password workflow.    If for some reason your confirmation workflow is interrupted, I think we received an error message that the user was not yet confirmed and diverted them back into the confirmation workflow.

Comment: I know this is very late, but adding a comment if someone wants this later. You can use lambda to change the email content and can specify multiple messages for multiple cases like signup, forget password like mentioned in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-message.html

Answer (score 0):

So Even I faced a same issue, Even in AWS cognito documentation it was not clear, basically the process involves two steps.

1. call cognitoUser.forgotPassword() this will start forgot password process flow, and the user will receive a verification code.
2. then call cognitoUser.confirmPassword() which will reset the password verifying the code send to the email of user.

Below I have given a cognitoUserClass which has static methods forgotPassword() and confirmPassword() methods which implements those two steps.

```
import * as AmazonCognitoIdentity from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js'

class cognitoUserClass {
    static cognitouser: AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser
    static userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool({
        UserPoolId: 'your pool id',
        ClientId: 'your client id',
    })
    static forgotPassword(userName: string): void {
        const userData = {
            Username: userName,
            Pool: cognitoUserClass.userPool,
        }
        cognitoUserClass.cognitouser = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser(
            userData
        )

        cognitoUserClass.cognitouser.forgotPassword({
            onSuccess: (data) => {
                console.log(data)
            },
            onFailure: (err) => {
                console.log('ERR:', err)
            },
        })
    }
    static confirmPassword(
        verificationCode: string,
        newPassword: string
    ): void {
        cognitoUserClass.cognitouser.confirmPassword(
            verificationCode,
            newPassword,
            {
                onFailure(err) {
                    console.log(err)
                },
                onSuccess(data) {
                    console.log(data)
                },
            }
        )
    }
}

export { cognitoUserClass }
```